# Spark sortmerge join failing with OOM, force operator spilling

Tags: apache-spark

I am joining a huge table which utilizes sort merge join. The operation goes OOM and I can see that peak JVM memory hits the limit from spark UI.

Adaptive plan:

```
+- AdaptiveSparkPlan (23)
   +- == Current Plan ==
      Project (14)
      +- SortMergeJoin Inner (13)
         :- Sort (6)
         :  +- ShuffleQueryStage (5)
         :     +- Exchange (4)
         :        +- * Filter (3)
         :           +- * ColumnarToRow (2)
         :              +- BatchScan (1)
         +- Sort (12)
            +- ShuffleQueryStage (11)
               +- Exchange (10)
                  +- * Filter (9)
                     +- * ColumnarToRow (8)
                        +- BatchScan (7)
```

This join fails as executors do not have enough memory. I decided to update config with low values using "spark.sql.sortMergeJoinExec.buffer.in.memory.threshold" "spark.sql.sortMergeJoinExec.buffer.spill.threshold". Ended up making the value as 50 (really low compared to million row I am scanning), however, the join still goes out of memory, there is no spilling. How can I make sure operator spilling happens, specifically for sort merge join?